# Color animation on Grid Control Row using Storyboard

Tags: wpf

I am using a third party grid control. I would like to animate row color from regular background to light green when MVVM property value changes to 'Success'

I have the following code

```
<dxg:GridControl.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridRowContent}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.State}" Value="Success">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                            From="White" To="LightGreen" Duration="0:0:5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</dxg:GridControl.RowStyle>
```

I am getting the following error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'ColorAnimation' (HashCode=47149397); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')

I have to somehow get the reference to the object of type `dxg:GridRowContent` for `Target` of Storyboard. Mode=FindAncestor does not find it either.

Any clue ?

Comment: did you try skipping `Target` altogether and change `TargetProperty` to `Backgorund.Color`?

Comment: @dkozl Please post your comment as an answer. It worked.

Comment: sure, [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844557/color-animation-on-grid-control-row-using-storyboard/24844762#24844762) added

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set `Storyboard.Target` as by default it should apply to your row and change `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to `Background.Color` as this is `ColorAnimation` and `Background` is a `Brush`

```
<ColorAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
    From="White" 
    To="LightGreen" 
    Duration="0:0:5" />
```